# Rounded rect radius calculation

Tags: vb.net, winforms, math, graphics

I have the following code to draw a rounded rect.

I would like to use the argument "RoundnessPercent" instead of using the radius.

[image]

(But shapes come from the same rectangle, but use different "roundness percent" values.

However, I just can't get my function to calculate the rest from it correctly.
I see all kinds of arkward rounded-rect appearances...

Could anybody with a mathematical understanding have a look at my function?

Thank you very much!

```
Public Function RoundedRect(ByVal uRect As Rectangle, ByVal uPercent As Integer) As GraphicsPath

    Debug.Assert(uRect.Width > 0)
    Debug.Assert(uRect.Height > 0)

    Dim iMinimum As Integer
    If uRect.Width > uRect.Height Then
        iMinimum = uRect.Height
    Else
        iMinimum = uRect.Width
    End If

    Dim iRadius As Integer = ((iMinimum * uPercent) / 100) 'I think this where I introduce a flaw

    Dim nPath As New GraphicsPath
    nPath.AddLine(uRect.Left + iRadius, uRect.Top, uRect.Right - iRadius, uRect.Top)
    nPath.AddArc(Rectangle.FromLTRB(uRect.Right - iRadius, uRect.Top, uRect.Right, uRect.Top + iRadius), -90, 90)
    nPath.AddLine(uRect.Right, uRect.Top + iRadius, uRect.Right, uRect.Bottom - iRadius)
    nPath.AddArc(Rectangle.FromLTRB(uRect.Right - iRadius, uRect.Bottom - iRadius, uRect.Right, uRect.Bottom), 0, 90)
    nPath.AddLine(uRect.Right - iRadius, uRect.Bottom, uRect.Left + iRadius, uRect.Bottom)
    nPath.AddArc(Rectangle.FromLTRB(uRect.Left, uRect.Bottom - iRadius, uRect.Left + iRadius, uRect.Bottom), 90, 90)
    nPath.AddLine(uRect.Left, uRect.Bottom - iRadius, uRect.Left, uRect.Top + iRadius)
    nPath.AddArc(Rectangle.FromLTRB(uRect.Left, uRect.Top, uRect.Left + iRadius, uRect.Top + iRadius), 180, 90)
    nPath.CloseFigure()

    Return nPath

End Function
```

What I am getting is this (after the change suggestion):

[image]

Comment: Just a tip, you may want to consider using [Math.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.min(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I don't think you want to divide by two.  Try just `Dim iRadius As Integer = iMinimum * (uPercent / 100)`  You can probably commment out the AddLine codes, too.

Comment: Have you written your formula out with pencil and paper?  It can help you work out what you are doing.  You have two cases.  Plug those numbers in and see if you are getting your expected answer.

Comment: @LarsTech Dear Lars, thank you. I have changed my post accordingly. It shows one (last) flaw (I hope). Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: AddArc() requires the bounding rectangle of the arc, as though it was a full circle.  So you need to use 2 * iRadius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
Public Function RoundedRect(ByVal uRect As Rectangle, ByVal uPercent As Integer) As GraphicsPath

    Debug.Assert(uRect.Width > 0)
    Debug.Assert(uRect.Height > 0)

    Dim iMinimum As Integer
    If uRect.Width > uRect.Height Then
        iMinimum = uRect.Height
    Else
        iMinimum = uRect.Width
    End If

    Dim iRadius As Integer = iMinimum * (uPercent / 100)
    iRadius = Math.Max(iRadius, 1)

    Dim nPath As New GraphicsPath
    nPath.AddLine(uRect.Left + (iRadius \ 2), uRect.Top, uRect.Right - (iRadius \ 2), uRect.Top) 'top line
    nPath.AddArc(Rectangle.FromLTRB(uRect.Right - iRadius, uRect.Top, uRect.Right, uRect.Top + iRadius), -90, 90)
    nPath.AddLine(uRect.Right, uRect.Top + (iRadius \ 2), uRect.Right, uRect.Bottom - (iRadius \ 2)) 'right line
    nPath.AddArc(Rectangle.FromLTRB(uRect.Right - iRadius, uRect.Bottom - iRadius, uRect.Right, uRect.Bottom), 0, 90)
    nPath.AddLine(uRect.Right - (iRadius \ 2), uRect.Bottom, uRect.Left + (iRadius \ 2), uRect.Bottom) 'bottom line
    nPath.AddArc(Rectangle.FromLTRB(uRect.Left, uRect.Bottom - iRadius, uRect.Left + iRadius, uRect.Bottom), 90, 90)
    nPath.AddLine(uRect.Left, uRect.Bottom - (iRadius \ 2), uRect.Left, uRect.Top + (iRadius \ 2)) 'left line
    nPath.AddArc(Rectangle.FromLTRB(uRect.Left, uRect.Top, uRect.Left + iRadius, uRect.Top + iRadius), 180, 90)
    nPath.CloseFigure()

    Return nPath

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I re-worked the AddArc coordinates, basically resizing the corner rectangles:

```
Dim factor As Decimal = uPercent / 100

Dim nPath As New GraphicsPath
nPath.StartFigure()
nPath.AddArc(New Rectangle(uRect.Right - (uRect.Width * factor),
                           uRect.Top,
                           uRect.Width * factor,
                           uRect.Height * factor), -90, 90)
nPath.AddArc(New Rectangle(uRect.Right - (uRect.Width * factor),
                           uRect.Bottom - (uRect.Height * factor),
                           uRect.Width * factor,
                           uRect.Height * factor), 0, 90)
nPath.AddArc(New Rectangle(uRect.Left,
                           uRect.Bottom - (uRect.Height * factor),
                           uRect.Width * factor,
                           uRect.Height * factor), 90, 90)
nPath.AddArc(New Rectangle(uRect.Left,
                           uRect.Top,
                           uRect.Width * factor,
                           uRect.Height * factor), 180, 90)
nPath.CloseFigure()
Return nPath
```

My results using 99%:

[image]

Here I restored the minimum size:

```
Public Function RoundedRect(ByVal uRect As Rectangle, ByVal uPercent As Integer) As GraphicsPath
  Dim minSize As Integer = Math.Min(uRect.Width, uRect.Height) * (uPercent / 100)
  Dim nPath As New GraphicsPath
  nPath.StartFigure()
  nPath.AddArc(New Rectangle(uRect.Right - minSize, uRect.Top, minSize, minSize), -90, 90)
  nPath.AddArc(New Rectangle(uRect.Right - minSize, uRect.Bottom - minSize, minSize, minSize), 0, 90)
  nPath.AddArc(New Rectangle(uRect.Left, uRect.Bottom - minSize, minSize, minSize), 90, 90)
  nPath.AddArc(New Rectangle(uRect.Left, uRect.Top, minSize, minSize), 180, 90)
  nPath.CloseFigure()
  Return nPath
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Lars, this looks really good, but it is not really what I desired to do.

Comment: @tmighty Then I guess that part is unclear from your question. You added that oval to your post, but you didn't state what was wrong with it.

Comment: I have those two lines that should not be there.

Comment: I am not sure if you saw this resulting image in my post.

Comment: @tmighty I don't get those two lines with my code.  The rectangles you see in my screen shot were drawn rectangles for perspective.

Comment: I really admire you code, but it doesn't really reflect what I am trying to achieve. To be honest, I am too dumb with maths to fix it myself. Do you think you might be able to help?

Comment: To be even more honest, I don't even understand all the magic that is beyond the screenshot that I posted. It is from an image editor software, and I am trying to accomplish the same.

Comment: @tmighty I updated the post.  If it's still not what you are looking for, then please, can you explicitly point out what is wrong with it?